# I want to evaluate Android stability with Monkey test. Is there any suggestion about execution time?

Tags: android, testing, monkey

We are working on customizing Android and need evaluate Android system stability. 
Plan to use 9 Android phones and run Monkey once a day. However, the execution time for each day and testing how many days is hard to determine by us. Is there any practice or principle for this shared?

Comment: What exactly are you planning to do?

Comment: we are evaluating the customized Android system stability, with some KPI like MTBF (mean time between failures). It needs some continous testing during some time. We have setup 9 cellphones and run Monkey in parallel. But we are still not decided how many rounds and hours (500 or 1000?) to be run for this testing.

Comment: This seems like a question for a standard of testing protocol. In this particular case, I recommend that you consult your advisor/manager. It is a subjective question. Good Luck! (Y)

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: actually, it is not subjective. It should be some objective criteria. The criteria should be from some real practice, industry standards, or something similar.

Comment: Well, what I meant with subjective was that the feature you are providing in the customized Android system needs to to be evaluated in its context. You might want to look into how other similar systems are evaluated.